# Comparing array members with nest loop,counting how many times the condition(if) was met

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, compare, nested-loops

I'm comparing three different arrays , in my case , my program is checking with how many other circles one particular circle intersects. My function that does that :

```
void Intersection(int n, int A[], int B[], int C[]) 
{
ofstream out(rez);
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
       times_condition_met=0;
         for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
         {
             if (Distance(X, Y, i, j) < (Radius[i] + Radius[j]))
             {
                 times_condition_met++;
             } 
         }
     }
}
```

I've my coordinates of circles centers and radii in three different arrays.

```
 X[] Y[] and R[]
```

This is the condition that has to be met

```
if (Distance(X, Y, i, j) < (Radius[i] + Radius[j]))
            times_condition_met++;
```

The function   `Distance` finds the distance between two points (between centers of circles).

The problem I've met when counting with how many other circles does one particular circle intersect with is that when my function is checking if the condition is met e.g. if `Circle1` intersects with `Circle2` `times_condition_met++` and then some time later loop checks if `Circle2` intersects with `Circle1` it does `times_condition_met++` again. So what kind of `if` I should use so `Circle1` intersects with `Circle2` and `Circle2` intersects with `Circle1` would be counted as the condition was met only one time instead of two?

Comment: If Circle 1 intersects with Circle 2, then Circle 2 will intersect with Circle 1. So regardless, what you are seeking is times_condition_met/2.

Comment: I've already found the solution, but thanks for replying! Maybe you could help me out with another thing ? I need to find which circle(index of it) intersects with the most circles,I know the `if` statement I need,but I don't know how to find the index of that particular circle which intersects with the most circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is your for-loop that needs to be updated.

Try:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)   // Update here
     {
       times_condition_met=0;
         for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) // Update here
```

In this way you'll only compare two specific circles one time.

In the first loop circle 0 will be compared to circle 1,2,..,n-1

In the second loop circle 1 will be compared to circle 2,3,..,n-1

In the third loop circle 2 will be compared to circle 3,4,..,n-1

and so on...

In the last loop circle n-2 will be compared to circle n-1

All together - any pair of circles is only checked once.

For counting which circle intersects with most circles, you can do like this:

```
   // Make a vector with n elements - all initialized to zero
   std::vector hitcounter(n, 0); 

   for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
   {
        times_condition_met=0;
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        {
             if (Distance(X, Y, i, j) < (Radius[i] + Radius[j]))
             {
                 times_condition_met++;

                 // increment hit counter
                 hitcounter[i] = hitcounter[i] + 1;
                 hitcounter[j] = hitcounter[j] + 1;
             } 
        }
   }

   int top = -1;
   int topIndex = -1;
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       if (hitcounter[i] > top)
       {
           top = hitcounter[i];
           topIndex = i;
       }
   }

   if (top == -1)
   {
       cout << "No intersect found" << endl;
   }
   else
   {
       cout << "Most intersect found for circle " << topIndex << " Hits=" << top << endl;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working fine now, I was thinking I needed some seperate if statement.. By the way, I also need so that the function would return me the index of the circle,which intersects with the most circles. F.e. `7th circle intersects with the most circles.` Maybe you could help me out with that as well ?

Comment: You're welcome :-) It could have been done with an extra if-statement but that would have been more complicated and performed worse.

Comment: I also need to find which of the given circles (index of it) intersects with the most other circles. I know the `if` statement I need, but I don't know how to find the index of that particular circle. Maybe you could me ? I would be very thankful.

Comment: I'll be happy to help but... Raise it as a new question - post the code you have including whatever idea you have to solve the problem. Then I or some else will help.

Comment: I would have already done that if I could. I will be able to ask my next question in 2 days,because I already asked one question today and I need to get it done until tomorrow.. So I have no other choice.